# Django relation doesnt work?

Tags: database, django, model, relational

I have the following in models:

```
  class Companies(models.Model):
    ComName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ComURL = models.CharField(max_length=1024,null=True)

  class Products(models.Model):
    PrName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    PrCompany =  models.ForeignKey(Companies)
```

and the following in the template:

```
  {% if products %}
    var markers = [
    {% for product in products %}{"url":"{{ product.PrCompany.ComURL }}","name":"{{ product.PrName }}"},{% endfor %}
    ]
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

but the output i get is:

```
var markers = [
{"url":"None","name":"Samsung GT-S7350"},{"url":"None","name":"SonyEricsson W395"},{"url":"None","name":"Nokia E75"},
]
```

I look in the database, and each entry has a value in there, which is not empty.
Why does it say "None" ?
Something is not right in the relation?

Comment: What is the output when you use {{ product.PrCompany }}? This will give you a hint as to what records are being accessed.

Comment: Interesting. If i do that, i get the name of the company? So guessing the relation works, but why dont i get the URL then? Is perhaps URL a reserved word of some sort?

Comment: Well, I suppose the next test would be to input a harmless string into one of the ComURL fields --- if you change the value to 'foo', do you still get 'None' returned on those records?

Comment: Found it... Apparently i was looking at one database, while i had the setup to another database. The database I was looking at was an older one, and the discrepancy in models was what was causing this.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try models.URLField() instead of a CharField for the ComURL.

Comment: if i use URLfield that all URL's have to be unique, which is not something i want.